# InputStream read(byte[] b) buffering input

Tags: java, inputstream, printwriter

I have found a Fast I/O class for java which exploits InpuStream read(byte[] b) method . Here is the class : (Problem relates to readInt() ... Can skip rest of class details )

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class FastInput
{


        private InputStream stream;
        private byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        private int curChar;
        private int numChars;


        public FastInput(InputStream userInputStream)
        {
            this.stream = userInputStream;

        }


        public int readChar()
        {

            if (numChars == -1)
                throw new InputMismatchException();

            if (curChar >= numChars)
            {

                curChar = 0;

                try
                {
                    numChars = stream.read(buf);
                } 
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    throw new InputMismatchException();
                }

                if (numChars <= 0)
                    return -1;

            }

            return buf[curChar++];

        }


        public boolean isSpaceChar(int c) 
        {

                return c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\r' || c == '\t' || c == -1;

        }


        public int readInt()
        {

            int c = readChar();
            int sgn = 1;

            while (isSpaceChar(c))
                c = readChar();

            if (c == '-' )
            {
                sgn = -1;
                c = readChar();

            }

            int res = 0;

            do {

                if (c < '0' || c > '9')
                    throw new InputMismatchException();

                res *= 10;
                res += c - '0';
                c = readChar();

            } while (!isSpaceChar(c));

            return res * sgn;

        }

        public long readLong()
        {

            int c = readChar();
            int sgn = 1;

            while (isSpaceChar(c))
                c = readChar();

            if (c == '-' )
            {
                sgn = -1;
                c = readChar();

            }

            long res = 0;

            do {

                if (c < '0' || c > '9')
                    throw new InputMismatchException();

                res *= 10;
                res += c - '0';
                c = readChar();

            } while (!isSpaceChar(c));

            return res * sgn;

        }



        public String readString() {

            int c = readChar();

            while (isSpaceChar(c))
                c = readChar();

            StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();

            do
            {

                res.append(c);
                c = readChar();

            } while (!isSpaceChar(c));


            return res.toString();

        }

        // The method created intially skips all whitespaces as defined above and then starts reading everything before \r , \n  , or both
        public String readLine()
        {
                int c=  readChar();

                while (isSpaceChar(c))
                    c = readChar();

                StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();

                do
                {
                    res.append(c);
                    c = readChar();

                }while (c != '\r' &&  c!= '\n');


                return res.toString();

        }


        public void close()
        {
                try
                {
                    stream.close();
                }
                catch(IOException ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();

                }
        }



}
```

Now , i decide to use it . Here is how i used it :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                FastInput input = new FastInput(System.in);
                PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(System.out);

                for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
                    output.printf("Hello your num = %d\n" , input.readInt());

                input.close();
                output.close();

        }

}
```

Both classes were in same package. Now , this is what I typed and the output I got :

```
G:\Java>java Main
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
Hello your num = 1
Hello your num = 2
Hello your num = 3
Hello your num = 4
Hello your num = 5
Hello your num = 6
Hello your num = 7
Hello your num = 8
Hello your num = 9
Hello your num = 10
```

Now , my question is why do I get all output collectively in end ? Also , How did read method knew when i would stop entering  10 numbers and then stop its buffering in Byte[] array (if this is how it behaved , i m not sure).

I tried to read java doc about it but nothing was mentioned about this thing.

> public int read(byte[] b)
>            throws IOException
>
> Reads some number of bytes from the input stream and stores them into
>   the buffer array b. The number of bytes actually read is returned as
>   an integer. This method blocks until input data is available, end of
>   file is detected, or an exception is thrown.
>
> If the length of b is zero, then no bytes are read and 0 is returned;
>   otherwise, there is an attempt to read at least one byte. If no byte
>   is available because the stream is at the end of the file, the value
>   -1 is returned; otherwise, at least one byte is read and stored into b.
>
> The first byte read is stored into element b[0], the next one into
>   b[1], and so on. The number of bytes read is, at most, equal to the
>   length of b. Let k be the number of bytes actually read; these bytes
>   will be stored in elements b[0] through b[k-1], leaving elements b[k]
>   through b[b.length-1] unaffected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have your output immediately, you must add `output.flush()` inside the for loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                FastInput input = new FastInput(System.in);
                PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(System.out);

                for(int i=0;i<10;++i) {
                    output.printf("Hello your num = %d\n" , input.readInt());
                    output.flush();
                }
                input.close();
                output.close();

        }
```

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Okay , I thought it was some problem in my newly built class . I just missed such a silly thing . Thanks

Comment: Alternatively you can construct the PrintWriter to autoflush:

PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);